# Contexto nos serviços e repositórios

Tags: asp.net-mvc, services, contexto

Na empresa que trabalho utilizamos asp.net mvc divididos em 2 projetos:

- web - **(base)**
- service - **(regras de negócio)**

Em diversos lugares já notei outros programadores utilizando o contexto direto (que extende o DbContext) nos serviços e já vi também utilizando um contexto onde contém todos os repositórios registrados:

## Exemplo contexto (DbContext)

```
var contexto = new DatabaseContext();
contexto.Produtos....
contexto.Pessoas....
```

## Exemplo repositórios

```
contexto.ProdutosRepositorio...
contexto.PessoasRepositorio...
```

Agora vem as dúvidas:

- Porque e em quais casos usar cada um?
- No segundo exemplo porque não usar um repositório genérico? não é mais prático?

Aproveitando...

- É má prática um serviço instanciar outro e fazer o uso desse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Porque e em quais casos usar cada um?

Acredito que utilizando ***DbContext*** diretamente, você acaba ficando atrelado/preso a tecnologia, sendo uma desvantagem caso vocês necessitem mudar no futuro.

Outra desvantagem de usar ***DbContext*** diretamente no serviço é que seu serviço envolve regras de negócio, já ***DbContext*** está relacionado a uma tecnologia. Assim, se você mudar a tecnologia, vai precisar mexer no código onde estão suas regras de negócio, isso não é legal.

> No segundo exemplo porque não usar um repositório genérico? não é mais prático?

***Repository*** isola os objetos de domínio (relacionados ao negócio) de detalhes do código de acesso e mapeamento desses objetos com o banco de dados. Ou seja, ele adiciona uma camada de separação entre as camadas de acesso a dados e de domínio.

No caso do projeto que vocês estão desenvolvendo, vocês teriam que criar outro projeto na sua solução para implementar esse *design pattern*. Acredito ser mais prático e recomendável utilizar esse padrão.

> É má prática um serviço instanciar outro e fazer o uso desse?

**Não**, cada serviço tem sua responsabilidade e em muitos casos um serviço pode precisar de um outro serviço.

Exemplo: Em um cenário onde um Cliente faz um saque na sua conta, vamos supor que o Cliente tenha um serviço chamado ClienteServico.

```
public class ClienteServico
{
   //...
   public void RealizarSaque()
   {
      //Nesse ponto pode ser que o cliente não tenha saldo para saque
      //e você precisa de um serviço de um objeto ContaCorrenteServiço
      //por exemplo para retornar/verificar o saldo antes do saque
   }
   //...
}
```

Seguindo esse raciocínio, recomendaria a você também trabalhar com injeção de dependência e inversão de controle dos repositórios/serviços, conforme a resposta do Thiago Custodio (mas não apenas nos controllers, também nos seus serviços que dependerão de consultas aos repositórios, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

O Ideal seria injetar os repositórios / serviços nos controllers. Desta maneira, você consegue automatizar testes sem de fato bater no banco.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: Mas o controller não deveria apenas chamar os serviços?

Comment: Sim, a diferença é que você não irá instanciar os serviços nos controllers, mas sim recebê-los como dependência.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta mas fazendo uma pesquisa e diversos profissionais da área não recomendam o uso por diversas razões.

Comment: @bigown o que acha disso?

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez o que acha disso?

Comment: Acho desnecessário iniciar o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação sem que sejam bem entendidas as responsabilidades de um repositório. Para a grande maioria das aplicações, um repositório é completamente desnecessário, aumenta demais a complexidade entre camadas e ainda pode impactar no desempenho. Só justifica a injeção de dependências se a equipe de programadores optar por testes automatizados, como o @ThiagoCustodio afirmou em sua resposta.

Comment: @Apolo, bigown e cigano não foram notificados pelos seus comentários, [veja como as notificações realmente funcionam](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/943/como-funcionam-as-men%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-usuario). Independente disso, aqui geralmente não se "corre atrás" de determinado usuário para pedir opiniões ou esclarecimento (exceto no [chat]).

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião a segunda forma é a correta!

Esqueça DI não compensa!

Quanto ao repositório genérico é exatamente o que o nome diz... você pode usar um genérico ou um repositório para cada modelo, adapte conforme o processo e a evolução do seu projeto.

Se você optar por usar o repositório genérico no futuro ao criar um repositório especificado você precisa refatorar.